# c# Xamarin - System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I need to read an external JSON file, so I've used `System.IO.ReadAllText` with JSON.NET using this code:

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json
    .JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<String>(
        System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\arfmann\Desktop\json.json")
    );
```

But it gives me this error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/C:\Users\arfmann\Desktop\json.json"

Actually, the file exists and it's on the desktop, but, as you can see, it can't be found without any reason.
Any idea?

## PROBLEM SOLVED

Obv, the mobile app is running on a phone, so I can't acces to PC path. Here is the new code to acces to mobile path:

```
 Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
        string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"storage/emulated/0/Download/json.json"));
```

Comment: Maybe it's got a hidden extension

Comment: Wait, what are you talking about?

Comment: Why is there a slash before the drive letter in your error message?

Comment: No idea, i've alreay searched a reason without results. Maybe the problem it's this, but I don't know why

Comment: If the file is named something like `json.json.txt` and you're hiding "known extension", you wouldn't see it on the desktop.

Comment: the extension is .json, have I to add .txt anyway?

Comment: nope, it's showing file exentsions

Comment: your **MOBILE** app that runs on your **PHONE** cannot, at runtime, magically load files that are located on another machine

Comment: You're right, i feel pretty stupid now. Anyway, using phone path it says "Access denied", so another problem

Comment: Put it in the Assets folder of your application and get it with Assets.Open ("json.json")